# Input string was not in a correct format - When working with database

Tags: c#, android, database, xamarin

I'm working with xamarin in c# and it's with a database that has a list of users and each user has a list of their highest scores. I'm trying to update the list of scores with a new score like so:

```
public Score GetScore(DatabaseReference reference)
        {
            Score score = new Score();
            score.time = TimeSpan.ParseExact(reference.Child("Time").ToString(), @"hh\:mm\:ss\.fffffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            score.rightAnswers = int.Parse(reference.Child("Right Answers").ToString());
            score.genre = reference.Child("Genre").ToString();
            return score;
        }

        public async Task UpdateActivity(string username, Score score)
        {
            User user = await GetUser(username);
            DatabaseReference reference = GetDatabase().GetReference("Users").Child(user.userId);
            if (score != null)
            {
                if (await CheckIfScoreExists(username, score) == true)
                {
                    string id = await GetExistingScoreId(username, score);
                    DatabaseReference scoreRef = reference.Child("Scores").Child(id);
                    Score existingScore = GetScore(scoreRef);
                    if (score.IsHigher(existingScore))
                    {
                        reference.Child(id).RemoveValue();
                        HashMap newScore = new HashMap();
                        newScore.Put("Genre", score.genre);
                        newScore.Put("Time", score.time.ToString());
                        newScore.Put("Right Answers", score.rightAnswers);
                        reference.Child("Scores").Push().SetValue(newScore);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    HashMap newScore = new HashMap();
                    newScore.Put("Genre", score.genre);
                    newScore.Put("Time", score.time.ToString());
                    newScore.Put("Right Answers", score.rightAnswers);
                    reference.Child("Scores").Push().SetValue(newScore);
                }
                
            }
```

But when I run the app and try to update it says 'Input string was not in a correct format.' about the rightAnswers property. How can I fix that?

Note: the function GetExistingScoreId is in case a score in the genre of the given score already exists so I can replace the existing score if needed.

Comment: Whatever the value of `reference.Child("Right Answers")` is, it cannot be parsed to an int

Comment: @ConnorLow based on the error message, I'm sticking with my original comment. That is the location where a parse is attempted on the `rightAnswers` property.

Comment: @Crowcoder, I now see which line you are referring to and I think you are right, that's likely their issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @MeowSpaceCat. Are you able to run your app in debug mode and check the value of `reference.Child("Right Answers")` at runtime?

Comment: @Crowcoder the value is a pure int - 0, not even a string with any other chars that cannot be parsed.

Comment: Is your "rightAnswers" a property with some logic in "get"?
and Is it throw an exception exactly after passed this line "reference.Child("Right Answers")" when the value is 0?

Comment: @LLF I'm not sure what you meant in the first question, but about the second one - yeah it's exactly right after "reference.Child("Right Answers") and not only when the value is 0, it can also be 1 or 2 etc.

Comment: If it is an int then why do you ToString() it and then parse it? What line is throwing the exception?